# How do I know the accepted arguments in URL?

Tags: php, python, html, http, url

I want a way to know the available or allowed arguments in url

for example:

http://www.example.com/?name=aaa&id=123

but there might be another parameters but it is not visible like ( age=555&email=aa@bbb.com)

so most of urls will work even if I pass 1 parameter especially for search engine

but how can I know the available arguments that I can use?

thank you

Comment: Make a GET or POST request(accordingly) with the parameters which you are sending and you can confirm the request has sent to the server or not with the RESPONSE CODE.

Comment: The answer is unknowable. I can arbitrarily choose to accept any GET key I want and I can change it at any time. I don't have to tell you whether or not I accepted your values, so a RESPONSE CODE doesn't really help.

Comment: It depends on http://www.example.com documentation.. lol...

Comment: @TecBrat is correct - The code which digests the requests could take *args or **kwargs for infinitely possibilities.

Comment: @PigBall makes a point that I considered, but didn't include in my comment. If the site author wants you to know, then there will likely be documentation of the available keys and the expected value types. This is common for API web apps..

Comment: thank you guys for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments that a particular URL can accept are determined by the site's author. If they don't publish that information the only way you can *know* a particular argument is acceptable is to submit it and see whether you get an error response. Even then you won't know what range of values are acceptable.